# Установка netcat и других приложений в iSH(ios linux)

Tags: linux, эмулятор

В iSH у меня не получилось установить netcat(и несколько других приложений) через apk add(В инструкции говорится что нужно устанавливать через pkg add, но такой команды не существует). Может кто-то знает как можно другим способом установить эти приложения на iSH? Может через GitHub?

Comment: «не получилось» — это плохое описание выполненных вами действий и полученных результатов. пожалуйста, дополните вопрос, нажав [edit]. текстом, конечно, не картинкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробую угадать, что же вы делали, и какой результат получили.

```
$ apk add netcat
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  netcat (missing):
    required by: world[netcat]
```

означает это всего лишь то, что пакета с именем *netcat* нет в подключенных репозиториях.

что же делать? может быть, пакет называется как-то по-другому? поищем эту строку в именах и описаниях пакетов:

```
$ apk search netcat
netcat-openbsd-doc-1.130-r1
libusbmuxd-2.0.1-r0
netcat-openbsd-1.130-r1
```

так и есть! пакет назывется *netcat-openbsd*. устанавливаем:

```
$ apk add netcat-openbsd
(1/2) Installing libbsd (0.10.0-r0)
(2/2) Installing netcat-openbsd (1.130-r1)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r16.trigger
OK: 6 MiB in 16 packages
```

проверяем наличие программы:

```
$ command -v nc
/usr/bin/nc
```

всё получилось!

---

доп. чтение: [package management](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management)